# Can't create an roSGScreen object in Brightscript

Tags: oop, roku, brightscript

I am trying to create another screen and show it when the user clicks a button

```
sub showLiveScreen()
    print "Attempting to show the live screen"
    screen2 = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
    m.port2 = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    screen2.setMessagePort(m.port2) 'screen2 is invalid
    scene2 = screen2.CreateScene("LiveScene")
    screen2.show()

    while(true)
        msg = wait(0, m.port2)
        msgType = type(msg)
        if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
        if msg.isScreenClosed() then return
        end if
    end while
end sub
```

But it won't allow me to create a roSGScreen object here, even though this works in my main.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Creating a new Screen this way is only necessary if You are using non-SceneGraph SDK(which is old SDK and I don't recommend using it).
On the other hand, You can only create a new screen insade your main thread! You can't create a new screen from render/SceneGraph thread and from what I understand that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: downvote for just telling him the problem without code resolution. how would you write the code in the main thread? in ROKU it isn't trivial to find it fast in the documentation or their forums.